# Prove that a polynomial of two variables is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $n, m \ge 0$ be integers. Suppose that for every $0 \le i \le n$ and $0 \le j \le m$ we have a real number $c_{ij}$. From the function $P : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$P(x,y) : = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m c_{ij} x^i y^j.$$
Show that $P$ is continuous. Conclude that if $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions, then the function $P(f, g) : X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $P(f, g) (x) : = P(f(x), g(x))$ is also continuous.

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f+g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $fg : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $cf : X \to \mathbb{R}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I also know that $\pi_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\pi_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\pi_1(x,y) =x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$, respectively, are continuous. 
I also know that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

I need to somewhat manipulate this information to show that $P(x,y)$ is continuous, but I cannot do it by myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have all the necessary informatiom. All you have to do is to use induction on $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that

- $x: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $x(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \xi_1$ i.e. $x = \pi_1$.
- $y: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $y(\xi_1, \xi_2) = \xi_2$ i.e. $y = \pi_2$.

Then you know that $x,y$ are both continuous.

Now note that $x^i$ is multiplying the function $x$ by itself $i-1$ times. Hence also $x^i$ is continuous; same for $y^j$, and also $x^i y^j$.

Now note that $c_ij x^i y^j$ is scalar multiplication of a continuous function. Hence it is also continuous.

Finally, $\sum_i \sum_j c_ij x^i y^j$ is a finite summation of continuous functions and thus also continuous.